# Разделить контейнер на 6 частей по ширине без таблиц.

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть контейнер, содержащий шесть потомков, необходимо, чтобы потомки заполняли всю ширину контейнера, при этом ширина самих контейнеров должна зависеть от содержимого (если сделать их равными, содержимое некоторых ячеек будет выходить за границы).
Или же, как минимум нужно сделать, чтобы первый и последний потомки были прижаты к левой и правой границам контейнера соответственно.
Уважаемые коллеги, не подскажете ли метод решения подобной задачи без таблиц?

Comment: А контейнер резиновый?

Comment: Конкретно в этом случае - нет.

Comment: Тогда вроде ни как, т. к. или контейнер должен быть резиновым, или потомки фиксированными.

Comment: а если контейнер резиновый, как вы предлагаете это сделать?

Comment: Просто расположить их как вам надо, и сделать ширину и высоту на auto

Comment: А как же Inevitable Exception? Ну и в общем не заработало. Элементы так и остались шириной с содержимое.

Comment: что делать в случае если у контейнера ширина меньше, чем суммарная ширина внутренних элементов?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь может помочь *display:flex* у контейнера.
Если у контейнера задано свойство *display:flex*, то ширина внутренних блоков рассчитывается по ширине их содержимого. Чтобы последний элемент растянулся по всей оставшейся ширине необходимо для него использовать свойство: *flex-grow:1*

[Хорошее руководство по flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div div{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

div.main{
  display: flex;
}

div.last {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>first</div>
  <div>second with text</div>
  <div>third with long loong long loong long loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loonglong loong next</div>
  <div>fourth el</div>
  <div>fif</div>
  <div>six</div>
</div>  
<hr />
<div class="main">
  <div>first</div>
  <div>second with text</div>
  <div>third </div>
  <div>fourth el</div>
  <div>fif</div>
  <div class="last">six</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну так и было задуманно, а если хотите можете посмотреть тут http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/jquery/137436/ , там вроде есть то,что вам нужно про jQuery Masonry